# Magento 2 sometimes don't show items in the second category

Tags: magento-2.1, items, magento-2.1.1, category-view

I have two basic categories (woman/man) with many subcategories and products. Sometimes, just sometimes the products in the second category "man" don't appear in the frontend. In the backend they are still there.

Often after I do **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** the products still missing the first time and if I do it again they will be there.

My Magento Version is 2.1.1

Comment: Did you get solution I have same problem it's not showing products from subcategories

Comment: No, not yet. I still didn't have time to update to try if it happens in the newer version too.